# How to follow a country during the olympics (Google now)

Tags: google-now

I really like the job Google has done on their Olympic coverage. However I cannot for the life of me figure out how to add a country to follow during the Olympics. I am currently following the US because I was initially asked if I would like to follow them but I would like to follow other countries as well.

Is there any way to add additional countries to be followed via google now during the Olympics?

Comment: Change your home address to a different country might work.

Comment: @user181927 thank you, for some reason that's what determines your "country" for the Olympics. Because immigration isn't a thing

Comment: No Google just guess what your home country is via its AI. In my case because I use VPN sometimes it guessed my home country differently from time to time. My home address is in the US, but Google never guessed it is my home country and even if I turn off my VPN now it still doesn't guess it right.